# C# Empty object property List from another class

Tags: c#

So, I have problem with objects in list. The list is in `Student` class, named `ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow`, I initialize and fill it with objects in `DeansOffice` class.

When i try to show them in MessageBoxes in `DeansOffice` class, its normally show it, but when i try to show same MessageBoxes from `MainWindow` class, the same List is empty, and no objects were shown in MessageBoxes.

What am I doing wrong?

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetDataFromDb();
        StudentsDataGrid.ItemsSource = Student._ListaStudentow;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wnd = new DeansOffice();
        wnd.ShowDialog();

        if (wnd.NewStudent != null)
        {
            var NewStudent = wnd.NewStudent;
            foreach (Subject s in NewStudent.ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow)
                MessageBox.Show(s.Name);   //HERE they don't appear
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public partial class DeansOffice : Window
{
    public Student NewStudent { get; set; }
    public List StudentSubjects = new List();

    public DeansOffice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StudiaComboBox.ItemsSource = Studies._StudiesList;
        PrzedmiotyListBox.ItemsSource = Subject._SubjectList;
    }

    private void AddButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tmpNazwisko = NazwiskoTextBox.Text;
        var tmpImie = ImieTextBox.Text;
        var tmpNrIndeksu = NrIndeksuTextBox.Text;
        var StudentSubjects = Subject._SubjectList.Where(p => p.IsChecked == true);
        var AreSubjectsSelected = StudentSubjects.Any();

        if (tmpImie != "" && tmpNazwisko != "" && tmpNrIndeksu != "" && StudiaComboBox.SelectedItem != null && AreSubjectsSelected)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(tmpNrIndeksu, "^s[0-9]{4,5}$");
            var tmpStudia = ((Studies)StudiaComboBox.SelectedItem).Id;
            if (match.Success)
            {
                NewStudent = new Student
                {
                    Imie = tmpImie,
                    Nazwisko = tmpNazwisko,
                    NrIndeksu = tmpNrIndeksu,
                    IdStudia = tmpStudia,
                    ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow = StudentSubjects
                }; 
                foreach (Subject s in NewStudent.ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow)
                    MessageBox.Show(s.Name);   //HERE CheckBoxes appear
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `Subject` object and where you initialize it?

Comment: The list is empty bucause the NewStudent object is emply in the mainwindow class

Comment: Try `ListaPolishWords = StudentSubjects.ToList()`?

Comment: @AlaaeddineHFIDHI - What makes you say that?

Comment: @Fabio ```Subject``` objects are initialized earlier. I think they are good beacuse in ```DeansOffice``` MessageBoxes show them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Blorgbeard said. 
Changing `ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow = StudentSubjects` to `ListaWybranychPrzedmiotow = StudentSubjects.ToList()` in creating new `Student` object in `DeansOffice` class, works.

Thank you!